# jQuery find full class name using partial string

Tags: jquery, class

I have slides with varying class names `'in-left' 'in-right' 'in-bottom'` ect. I need to first find any slide that has a class starting with `'in-'` but then I need to get the full class name 'in-left' to use for a switch statement. I am trying to find the most efficient way to do this, hopefully without a regex?

Normally I would use a data attribute `data-in="left"`, but can't for this project.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slide in-left"></div>
    <div class="slide in-right"></div>
    <div class="slide in-bottom"></div>
    <div class="slide in-top"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var $els = $('.slide[class*="in-"]');
$.each( $els, function(k, v){
  var type = v; // Get full class name for classes that start with 'in-'
  switch (type) { 
    case 'in-left':
      // Transition in from left
    break;
    case 'in-bottom':
      // Transition in from bottom
    break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use e.g `data-transition="left"` attribute? `Normally I would use a data attribute data-in="left", but can't for this project.` How that?

Comment: If you know all the class names, you could use a `switch` check, or just use `$(this).attr('class')` in your `.each` function to find all of the classes it has.

Comment: While the `hasClass()` approach is probably easiest, what sort of result did you want from the function you were trying to put together? An Object containing the Node and the 'full class'? Or a 2 dimensional array of some kind?

Comment: @Woff. I am adding a custom intro outro effects to 'Layer Slider' plugin for Wordpress. And the plugin Author only allows you to add classes to each slide not data attributes, so I am confined by that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about, if you know the possible values, to use [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$('.slide').each( function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('in-left')) {

  } else if ($this.hasClass('in-bottom')) {

  } /* else if() ... */
});
```

Comment: I agree that this should work well, but it presupposes you always know all of the class options ahead of time.

Comment: Well, I was basing my answer to the given information.. ^^

Comment: Yeah the user will be inputting these exact names, else it won't work or they will get a default chosen for them. I am wondering if hasClass with the if else chain will be expensive though. There shouldn't be anymore than 3 items being animated in at any one time however.

Comment: I think it will perform just fine, plus it would be more readable, no?

Answer (score 2):

While I would strongly advise that you go with [Toni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155758/82548), I wanted to offer an alternative solution to the problem, even thought it's not quite what you were asking for – though that's because you offered no clarity, or explanation, of where you wanted the 'full class-name' returned *to*.

This approach takes the prefixed class-names and then creates a `data-*` attribute on each element with the prefix-name; therefore the classes with the prefix of `"in-"` are used to generate a `data-in` attribute with the suffix of the class, following the `'-'` character becomes the attribute-value. So:

```
<div class="in-left"></div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="in-left" data-in="left"></div>
```

Which seems to be an appropriate solution to the problem you describe, and allows you to use your 'normal'/'preferred' syntax to access the relevant elements; though there's some ambguity and a lack of clarity of the desired result in your question as it stands.

That said, one approach is the following:

```
// creating a simple jQuery plugin:
(function ($) {

    // the plugin-name:
    $.fn.fullClassFromPartial = function (opts) {

        // extending the 'defaults' with the
        // options supplied by the user:
        var s = $.extend({
            'partial': '',
            'join' : ''
        }, opts);

        // we proceed only if the user supplies a
        // value for the s.partial property:
        if (s.partial.length) {

            // returning the jQuery collection (this),
            // after iterating through that collection
            // using the each() method:
            return this.each(function (i, n) {

                // setting the data-* attribute equal
                // to the value of the s.partial value
                // after replacing non-alpha characters:
                n.dataset[s.partial.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')] =

                   // setting the attribute-value, first
                   // using Function.prototype.call() to
                   // allow us to use Array.prototype.slice()
                   // on the Array-like return-value of
                   // the HTMLElement.classList property
                   // to convert the Array-like value into
                   // an Array:
                   Array.prototype.slice.call(n.classList, 0)

                       // using Array.prototype.filter()
                       // to retain only those elements
                       // upon whom the inner assessment
                       // returns a true/truthy value:
                       .filter(function (cN, i) {
                           // within the anonymous function the
                           // first argument ('cN') is the array
                           // element of the array over which
                           // we're iterating; the second argument
                           // ('i') is the index of that array-element
                           // in the Array.

                               // if the s.partial value is found at
                               // the beginning of the array-value,
                               // we retain this element in the array:
                               return cN.indexOf(s.partial) === 0;

                            // we convert into a map, using
                            // using Array.prototype.map()
                            // in order to create/return a new
                            // Array:
                            }).map(function (cN) {

                                // here we return the class-name
                                // after removing the s.partial
                                // prefix from it:
                                return cN.replace(s.partial, '');

                // should multiple attribute-values prefixed with
                // the same string exist, then we join them together
                // with the value supplied to the s.join property
                // which can be updated by the user via the 
                // supplied options:
                }).join(s.join);
            });

        // 
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    };

})(jQuery);

// calling the plugin (note that while I haven't restricted
// the selector to only those elements whose class contains
// the 'in-' string, that is definitely recommended (this is
// just a simple demo, though, and I want to show it working
// with a larger-than-necessary collection):
$('div').fullClassFromPartial({

    // setting the 'partial' property to the prefix
    // we're looking for:
    'partial': "in-",

    // setting the 'join' property to the string
    // with which we want to join multiple values
    // together:
    'join' : '_'
});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fullClassFromPartial = function(opts) {
    var s = $.extend({
      'partial': '',
      'join': ' '
    }, opts);

    if (s.partial.length) {
      return this.each(function(i, n) {
        n.dataset[s.partial.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')] = Array.prototype.slice.call(n.classList, 0).filter(function(cN, i) {
          return cN.indexOf(s.partial) === 0;
        }).map(function(cN) {
          return cN.replace(s.partial, '');
        }).join(s.join || ' ');
      });
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  };

})(jQuery);

$('div[class*="in-"]').fullClassFromPartial({
  'partial': "in-",
  'join': '_'
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  min-height: 2px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
[data-in]::before {
  content: attr(data-in);
}
[data-in=left] {
  border-left-color: #f90;
}
[data-in=right] {
  border-right-color: #f90;
}
[data-in=top] {
  border-top-color: #f90;
}
[data-in=bottom] {
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
}
[data-in=top_left] {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide in-top"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="slide in-right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="slide in-bottom"></div>
  <div class="in-bottom slide"></div>
  <div class="slide in-left"></div>
  <div class="slide in-top in-left"></div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yuewzco7/), for experimentation and development.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions (MDN Guide)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each).
  - [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: Thanks David, I implemented Toni's answer it's working good. I had thought before I posted my question about taking the class names and converting them to data attributes like you mentioned, but for the sake of performance I decided to go this way.  But now that you brought it up again might actually be a good way to go. There is an event that fires on the slider init() where I could do the conversions to data attributes and then my code will run faster on the slide in and slide out events. hmm ;)

Comment: No worries, and you are very welcome indeed! Note that I do recommend Toni's answer (simply for ease of use), but I left this solution almost purely to address the fundamental question you asked (and because it was fun to solve). In future, though, I'd advise that you take a little more time to specify your required/expected result - because being asked to find the 'full class name' is easy enough to do, but I had no idea where you wanted it to be returned (hence I used the `data-*` attribute purely as a demonstration of how to find/use that found  class-name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with this:

```
var $els = $('.slide[class*="in-"]');
$.each( $els, function(k, v){

  var type ='';
    type = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  if(type.indexOf('in-')==-1)
    type = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];

  switch (type) { 
    case 'in-left':
      // Transition in from left
    break;
    case 'in-bottom':
      // Transition in from bottom
    break;
  }
});
```

This will solve your problem. [Click here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aksdj3a/)

Comment: This presumes that the `in-` prefixed class-name will always be the second class-name in the class attribute; this seems an unrealistic assumption, despite that being true in the demo.

Comment: Yes, its will answer acc. to the html in question, i have another solution with some modification in this for weather is it first class or second class. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Check my edited answer and jsfiddle, there is html div where in- contain class also at first place. http://jsfiddle.net/4aksdj3a/

Comment: Umesh, do you think this approach would be less expensive than using hasClass?

Comment: I can say that switch case statement is better approach than if else statment. Switch case jump directly to matched case, but if statement check every condition whenever not matched.